# How to input an array into INSERT INTO query?

Tags: php, mysql

My array:

```
print_r($entryarray) = Array ( [Place] => lucky [Location] => India [Time] => [Info] => beautiful )
```

My code to insert the array into INSERT query:

```
if(count($entryarray) >0 ) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO testing (";
        foreach($entryarray as $col => $val){
            $query.="$col,";
        }
        $query.=" )
        VALUES(";
        foreach($entryarray as $col => $val){
            $query.="$val,";
        }
        $query.=" )";
}
```

But I am getting an error.

> Error: INSERT INTO testing (Place,Location,Time,Info, ) VALUES
>   array_values(lucky,India,,beautiful, )

How can I get `INSERT INTO testing ("Place", "Location", "Time", "Info").............`?

Comment: What is `array_values` doing in your SQL code?

Comment: Ya, my mistake. I removed it but still getting same error.

Comment: You can't get the (exactly) same error. However.. you are missing the quotes. But you should you should use a prepared statement. See [how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). BTW: With laravels querybuilder it would be `DB::table('testing')->insert($entryarray);`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
$keys = implode(",", array_keys($entryarray));
$vals = implode("','", array_values($entryarray));

$query = "INSERT INTO testing ('$keys') VALUES ('$vals')";
```

As mickmackusa suggested, you should sanitize any user input.

Comment: Thank you. But still can't resolve it.
Error: INSERT INTO testing ('Place','Location','Time','Info') VALUES ('lucky','India','','beautiful')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Place','Location','Time','Info') VALUES ('lucky','India','','beautiful')' at line 1

Comment: The query looks ok to me, does time allow null values? Are the colum names right?

Comment: I set the time to be a timestamp. So it will take it automatically.

Comment: I figured it. It has to be, INSERT INTO testing (Place,Location,Time,Info)
So I changed your code 
$keys = implode(",", array_keys($entryarray));

Comment: Good catch, I've updated my answer.

Comment: If this data is from user input, then this solution is insecure.

Comment: This solution will break if a user submits a value containing a apostrophe.  These types of answers are quick to write and lead unknowing researchers to write bad/insecure/unstable code.  Only use a preprared statement with bound parameters.